# AWS Cognito - Encountering Error Converting Circular Structure to JSON

Tags: amazon-cognito

I am trying to setup Cognito UnAuthenticated creds for users coming to my site. However, I am encountering "Error Converting Circular Structure to JSON" after the user id is assigned from Cognito and I am calling the synchronize method on the Sync Manager... please see the code below..

Any help in resolving this is greatly appreciated

```js
// Initialize the Amazon Cognito credentials provider
AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1'; // Region
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
   IdentityPoolId: 'us-east-1:my-id-pool-id'
});
 
function getMeACognito() {
    AWS.config.credentials.get(function(){
        var syncClient = new AWS.CognitoSyncManager();
 
        syncClient.openOrCreateDataset('yaHeardPrefs', function(err, dataset) {
 
            dataset.put('userPrefs', 'samplePrefs', function(err, record){
                if(err)
                {
                    console.log('(Sync error)Received error while saving prefs = ' + err);
                }
 
                dataset.synchronize({
                    onSuccess: function(data, newRecords) {
                        console.log('success');
                    },
                    onFailure: function(err){
                        console.log('Error while sync = ' + err);
                    },
                    onConflict: function(err) {
                        console.log('error / conflict = ' + err);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
```

and the error i am getting is -

```
aws-sdk-2.3.15.min.js:25 Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

Note that I do understand what a circular structure conversion error in JSON is based on few google searches... However, I am not in control of the JSON object being created by Cognito library here... and hence, need help in figuring out a path to resolution. If any of you have faced this before and had a solution for this, please reply.

Comment: Are you also seeing an error from the "dataset.put" operation? You code is continuing to "dataset.synchronize" even if there is an error from previous call. I am not sure how this will cause circular reference error but seems like a problem in the code. Can you change this flow and see if this goes away?

Comment: Hello, was this resolved, what was the fix? I'm experiencing a similar issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49417859/amazon-cognito-confirmpassword-fails-with-typeerror-converting-circular-struct. Can you post the solution please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my application above, for every new Cognito user created at the browser client, I was creating a new dataset and adding some info to it.

I had also setup Cognito to trigger a Lambda function for user creates.

Hence, during new user creations, Cognito was triggering the Lambda function and was synchronously waiting for the function to return successfully before marking the user dataset update operation as "complete" / "successful".

Within the Lambda function, I was also trying to update the same dataset for the user that was created at the browser with some additional information. This seems to have triggered a update back to the Cognito browser client. Afterall the prime functionality of Cognito is to keep its various clients at sync as user's info changes.

As stated in the [SO answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49417859/amazon-cognito-confirmpassword-fails-with-typeerror-converting-circular-struct?noredirect=1&lq=1), this went away when I stopped trying to update the same dataset at client and the lambda function at the same time.